# Advice to create a little script to associate near shipping address in the next 3 weeks

Tags: sql-server-2005

Hi guys I'm searching an advice on how to proceed to create a script that can calculate the distance between all shipping address in the next 3 weeks and if the distance between some of these locations is under 50 km it must send an email to make that thing notice to the operator. I'm starting from sql 2005 to take location and make all combination. Then I was thinking if there is some online service that, with a link structure where I can put the two location name, can retrieve the distance between those two point, then store it in different variable to use to make comparisons. I'll wait for some advice.thank you guys

Comment: Yes, it's called Google Maps API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script will probably take in 2 locations as parameters and you can determine the distance using [Google Maps Matrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) to get your distances from one place to another. Using that info you should be able to send an email using the script.

I'm not really sure what a database has to do with this so I recommend being more specific on your SQL implementation.

Comment: Yes, I've my erp that run in sql 2005. So I need to make a query executed from the sql agent to take all shipping locations in the next three weeks. Then I don't know if I can use directly from the agent also Google matrix. Or you can advice me on how to link those data with it?

Comment: Once you get the shipping locations, you should be able to calculate the distance between them. I don't know what sql agent you are using so it's hard for me to tell